# How to execute a function before to call another function

Tags: javascript

I have a button with an onClick calling a function that unfortunately I can't change. This function performs a login to the application:

```
<Button onClick={() => signIn()}>
```

but I need to execute some other code, to check if the user has checked a few checkboxes. Is there a way to call another function before the current one, and prevent the function call if the first one return false?

Comment: Not without changing the `onClick` or `signIn` function.

Comment: For me it’s not clear. Can you not change the onClick or not change the function login?

Comment: Make a function and call the signIn function at the end of it if it's required. (and replace the signIn function in the onclick event)

Comment: @palmarbg you actually right how couldn't think this myself? Sorry for the stupid friday question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the old `onclick` value, then replace it with your function that calls the original when it's done checking.

```
let oldFunc = button.onclick;
button.onclick = function(event) {
    // code to check if the checkboxes are checked
    if (boxes_checked) {
        if (typeof oldFunc == 'string') {
            eval(oldFunc);
        } else {
            return oldFunc(event);
        }
    }
}
```